# MATLAB Threshold multiple columns in a matrix, return row

Tags: matlab, matrix

I am studying skeletal co-ordinates and so far I have three joints with their x,y and z coordinates in a single matrice X. X is currently 214 x 9. In X, should be certain coordinates that match conditions I am investigating.

I want to be able to search each column using specific criteria, for example, column 1 (my x1 co-ordinate) must be > 0.1227 but < 0.120781. column 2 must be also fit within certain criteria and so forth.

At the moment my code looks like something like this,

```
R = X(X< 0.122781 & X > 0.120781);
```

which obviously is not working. When I try to introduce (:,1) in this code (for column 1) I don't get anywhere either. I haven't found much information on this but maybe I am missing something.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: asking for `x1` to be larger than 0.122 **and** smaller than 0.120 results in an empty set...

Answer (score 1):

You need to select the appropriate rows, then index `X`. You can do it as a "one-liner" but that might be difficult to read.

```
# example selecting according to first and second columns
row_sel = X(:,1) > 0.122 & X(:,1) < 0.2 & \
          X(:,2) > 0.43 & X(:,2) < 0.5 ; %// and so on...

R = X(row_sel,:); %// select the matching rows.
```

Comment: Brilliant, thank you. Is there a way to get R = X(row_sel,:); to output the entire row? so if 1 then entire row for all 9 columns.

Comment: @JoshRobertson please give it a try: `X(1,:)` gives the **entire** first row. Note the colon (`:`) for the second index indicating "all the columns".